# Adding animation between adding and removing two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am working on the demo below. Why am I not able to generate smooth transition (something like Smooth Scroll) between adding and removing two classes `fixed-top` and `fixed-bottom` while I already added following css roles into them?

```
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
```

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    if (st > 500) {
      $('.box').removeClass("fixed-bottom").addClass("fixed-top");
    }
  } else {
    if (st < 500) {
      $('.box').removeClass("fixed-top").addClass("fixed-bottom");
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #777;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box fixed-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this (having smooth moving up and down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stripe jumps up and down because you didn't set values of bottom within `.fixed-top` and top within `.fixed-bottom`, then transition prosessor can't realize wich attribute to transite. You need to get window.height() to transite properly. You can do it using jquery, wich makes your css shorter
Look at snippet

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var y = $( window ).height() - $('.box').height() + "px";
$('.box').css("top", y);
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    if (st > 500) {
      $('.box').css("bottom", y);
      $('.box').css("top","0");
    }
  } else {
    if (st < 500) {
      $('.box').css("top", y);
      $('.box').css("bottom","0");
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box fixed-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Banzay