# How to put a div from the top of my page to the bottom of it when i scroll to the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i hope my question is clear enought ! I have a div at the top of my page and i'd like that div to move at the bottom when i scroll and hit the end of the page, well i think you get the idea !

If anyone as an idea, i'm taking it ;)

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing much, i dont know how to achieve this at all ! Maybe by making my div fixed position and then getting it to the bottom with some script

Comment: Do you want to show fullscreen div when user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Comment: It's a form-group div with 2 col-sm-6 div inside, i want the all thing to be placed bottom

Comment: I think is possible get the page all height and scroll top position, with this two variable, is possible calculate scroll top percentage and you can use this result to set your div top position

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40773193/4206079

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scroll` event with `animate()` method, and use a flag `scroll` to make sure the div will be moved just one time :

```
var scroll = true;

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    var my_div = $("#my-div");

    if(scroll){
       scroll=false;

       my_div.animate({
          top : $('body').height() - my_div.offset().top - my_div.outerHeight(),
       }, 1000);
    }
})
```

Hope that will give you an idea.

```js
var scroll = true;

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
  var my_div = $("#my-div");

  if(scroll){
    scroll=false;

    my_div.animate({
      top : $('body').height() - my_div.offset().top - my_div.outerHeight(),
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
html, body { height: 500px; }

#my-div { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when user scroll to the bottom of the page and then transition top property from `0` to the height of the window minus height of that element.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    $('div').css({
      top: $(window).height() - $('div').height()
    });
  }
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/vyayKJ)